# How to make C# Windows Media Player COM available to Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows-explorer, windows-media-player, wmp, wmplib

I am using the Windows Media Player COM in C# with Visual Studio and with using the WindowsMediaPlayer interface class (not WindowsMediaPlayerClass) I can create a player that is controlled completely by my program and has no visible interface to the user.

My question, is it possible to make my instance of the WindowsMediaPlayer available to be added to the way you can add songs to the player from the file explorer?

[image: Example of adding to Windows Media Player]

I'd like to be able add songs through this method instead of having this Windows Explorer command open it's own instance of Windows Media Player (that is external from my program).

**Edit:**

I don't actually want to add a new entry to the right click menu in file explorer.  I would like the existing **Add to Windows Media Player list** to recognize my embedded WMP as the one it should add the songs to.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/

Comment: @HansPassant not quite, I'll update my question.  I don't want to add a new entry, I'd just like the existing entry to be able to add to my instance of the windows media player.

Comment: Do you want Add to Windows Media Player list menu item to add files both to WMP and your app? Or you want menu item to add files to your app only instead of WMP?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov ideally I would like the menu item to open the file in my app if my app is open (since it has a WMP instance in it) and if my app is not open it opens WMP like it regularly does any other time.

Comment: The program you are writing is for your own internal using? Or you will distribute it? If first what Windows version do you use?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov It is for my internal use currently.  I may distribute it for free if I feel like others may want to use it, so I'd prefer to avoid using any specific workarounds, plus it's just cleaner that way.

Comment: @DustinJensen is your problem solved? I have a similar problem!

Comment: @ACE unfortunately I never solved this problem! Sorry ACE.

Comment: @DustinJensen so bad :( as i said, I have this problem too. but i think it's getting solved! if i could solve it i will tell you. or if you want i tell you the way I'm solving it, so we could work on it together?

Comment: @ACE I would most interested in hearing how you are solving it! If I can be of any help I will.

Comment: @DustinJensen sry i read your message just right now. i had some problem that's the reason!
and yeah! by now I add an item to shell context menu and when user click on it if my program(music player) is running those files(songs) will add to its playlist. I think it solves your problem too ;)